# Are JSTL tags evaluated before

Tags: jsf, jstl

I am wondering why `getItems()` is called in the following view:

```
<p:panel rendered="false">
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.items}">
        ...
    </c:forEach>
</p:panel>
```

Are JSTL tags evaluated earlier then others? Is there any good documentation on this?

Comment: Actually, it's difficult to explain it better than the provided link ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for.